# deployment target 7 not showing uiimage in simulator

Tags: swift, ios7, uiimage, ios9, xcode7

I developed an application for iPhone with Xcode 7, and it works fine until I change the deployment target from 9 to 7.0.

When I do this, some images do not appear in the simulator, and 
when I set the deployment target back to 9, the images show again.

I removed the images and added it again (from assets).. but that is not working.

Comment: Probably you are using something which is not available in iOS 7.0. Make sure you are not using anything which is latest in iOS 9

Comment: May I know how have you assigned those images (code(mention the code you have written) / storyboard)?

Comment: I Changed the  Images to png , that worked for me .